# How to use function chaining with async function?

Tags: javascript, class, object, asynchronous, async-await

I'm currently writing an e2e test and I would like to create some classes which abstract certain async tasks for me. In the end I would like to instantiate an object, which let's me chain async functions. Let's say I have a `Walker` which let's me navigate through the page. I would like to use it in this way:

```js
const walker = new Walker(t)

await walker
  .goToMainPage()
  .goToProfile()
```

Currently I can only use it like this:

```js
const walker = new Walker(t)

await walker.goToMainPage()
await walker.goToProfile()
```

This is a rough implementation of how I currently implemented my Walker Class. Where `t` is and object which allows me to do asynchronous actions within my browser.

```js
class Walker {
  constructor(t) {
    this.t = t;
  }
  async goToMainPage () {
    await t.goTo('url/main')
    return this
  }
  async goToProfile () {
    await t.goTo('url/Profile')
    return this
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to create async chainable function calls?

Comment: I tried this code in a Codepen, and `return this;` only returns `Walker {t: undefined}`, with only `t` and without the two methods `goToMainPage` and `goToProfile`. I'm a bit puzzled by this. Why aren't the methods part of the instanciated class? Can someone explain?

Comment: @jeremy cause they are part of the prototype? `Walker { ... }` tells you about the inheritance...

Comment: @JeremyThille it is not code that should work properly, more like sudo code. I updated the example a litte. We would need to pass the `t` object during the instantiation of the class e.g. `new Walker(t)`. The t comes from another library I'm using. You can just think of it as a object which gives you a bunch of asynchronous functionality.

Comment: @JonasWilms so, are methods of a class only part of the prototype and not part of the class itself? That's weird

Comment: @jeremy Umm... `new Walker` is still an instance, and thats what `this` is pointing to. And yes, only `static` methods are part of the constructor itself, methods are part of the prototype. Remember: `class` is just syntactic sugar around constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`await` does not only work on Promises, but on every object that provides a `.then` handler ... therefore your Walker could implement a `.then` method to allow awaiting:

```
 class Walker {
   constructor(t) {
     this.t = t;
     // set up a task queue for chaining
     this.task = Promise.resolve();
    }

    // shedules a callback into the task queue
    doTask(cb) {
       // TODO: error handling
       return this.task = this.task.then(cb);
    }

    // allows to use this like a promise, e.g. "await walker";
    then(cb) { cb(this.task); }

    goToMainPage () {
      this.doTask(async () => { // shedule to chain
        await t.goTo('url/main')
      });
      return this; // return walker for chaining
   }

 }
```

That allows you to do:

```
 await walker.goToMainPage();
 await walker.goToMainPage().goToMainPage();
```

If you return something from inside `doTask`, `await`ing it will resolve to that:

```
 returnStuff() {
   this.doTask(() => "stuff");
   return this;
 }

 //...
 console.log(await walker.returnStuff()); // "stuff"
 console.log(await walker.returnStuff().goToMainPage()); // undefined, result gets lost
```

[Have fun with it!](https://jsbin.com/rurunefezi/edit?console)

Comment: This is a really neat solution

Comment: Basically we're delegating all promises until some code somewhere calls our `.then` handler. In the case of the OP's example code, the `.then()` will be invoked by `await`. Neat!

Comment: Could this be used to return a value? If goToMainPage were instead to modify the value of the variable "t" and you wanted a final method getValueOfT() to return that value at the end of the chain, how could you accomplish that?

Perhaps a function like so?  getValueOfT () { return this.doTask(() => this.t) }

Comment: @KyleR sure, but that sounds a lot like everyone trying to underatand your code will have a hard time ... :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `async/await` - it's essentially a replacement for Promise chaining (and Promises are themselves a solve for callback hell). If you *really* wanted to use chaining:

```
walker().then(w => w.goToMainPage()).then(w => w.goToProfile());
```

Comment: I do get that, but I would like to have the syntax I mentioned above. I know it is possible to get that kind of syntax if you build up the object / class in a certain way. The current e2e testing library (Testcafe) I'm using allows for that kind of syntax. So there must be a way to achieve that kind of object structure.